# png_set_tRNS not working libpng

Tags: c++, visual-c++, png, libpng

```
  FILE *PNGFile;
  png_structp PngPtr = NULL;
  png_infop InfoPtr = NULL;

  PNGFile = fopen(sFileName, "wb");
  PngPtr = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING,
     NULL, NULL, NULL);
  InfoPtr = png_create_info_struct(PngPtr);
  png_init_io(PngPtr, PNGFile);
  png_set_IHDR(PngPtr, InfoPtr, nWidth, nHeight, NumBits, PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE,
        PNG_INTERLACE_NONE, PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_DEFAULT, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_DEFAULT);
  png_set_PLTE(PngPtr, InfoPtr, PNGColor, NumColors); //NumColors = 256

  png_color_16 BGColor[1];
  png_byte TrnsColor[1];
  BGColor[0].index = 0;
  TrnsColor[0] = 100; //0 = transparent , 255 = opaque
  png_set_tRNS(PngPtr, InfoPtr, TrnsColor, 1, BGColor);
  png_write_info(PngPtr, InfoPtr);

  .......
  ........ //intialized image pixels

  png_write_image(PngPtr, PixelData);
  png_write_end(PngPtr, InfoPtr);
```

Using the above code I'm able to save the image but I'm not able to see the transparency for the pixels which is set using  "png_set_tRNS(PngPtr, InfoPtr, TrnsColor, 1, BGColor)".

When I read back the tRNS chunk using png_get_tRNS method for saved image, I'm able to get the values which I've set but not able to see the transparency when I open it with some image viewing applications.

Am I missing something in the code?

Comment: Thank You @GlennRanders-Pehrson I was setting alpha value for wronng index

Comment: I converted my two comments to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only going to affect any pixels with palette-index==0.

If you were expecting to see all of your pixels to be semitransparent, with alpha==100, then you need 256 entries in TrnsColor, all of them == 100.

By the way, you don't need BGColor[ ] when writing palette PNGs. Just use NULL for the last argument of png_set_tRNS.